# use the new version of ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I used to install ADT 18. in my new project, I have a menu with this code

```
    private void iniSlider(){       
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    NavDrawers = new ArrayList<>();
    NavDrawers.add(new NavDrawer(getString(R.string.title_section1),R.drawable.login,new Fragment()));
    NavDrawers.add(new NavDrawer(getString(R.string.title_section2),R.drawable.register,new Fragment()));               
    NavDrawers.add(new NavDrawer(getString(R.string.law),R.drawable.law,new Fragment()));

    View headerView = ((LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.drawer_header, null, false);                    
    mDrawerList.addHeaderView(headerView);
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),NavDrawers);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

and because of this line  `NavDrawers = new ArrayList<>();`
I have a error in eclipse :  Type '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

then I use the latest version of ADT,SDK,JRE
but I have this error, and I use android tools-> fix
it says :  Type Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead
and repeat from the begin
ps: I use appcompat az a lib in my project

do u know what is the problem and what should i do
my win is 8 and 64x

Answer (score 1):

Can't see your creation of `NavDrawers`, it's :

```
private ArrayList<NavDrawer> NavDrawers= new ArrayList<NavDrawer>();
```

Comment: Nope, only instantation at line 5.

Comment: I don't see where u declare your "NavDrawers" object.

Answer (score 0):

change from raw `ArrayList<>` to `ArrayList<NavDrawer>`

Comment: try to clean and build again.

Comment: when i clean the project, the errors go and after that they come back

Comment: In project properties, change compiler compliance level to 1.6, then clean and build.